# Intent shows null value while for Array List?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am passing **Array List** of string values to next activity,

some mobile it is working properly ,in some it does not pass values.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of the linked question! The linked question asks for clarification on HOW to pass an `ArrayList` in an `Intent`. Obviously OP is already doing this, so doesn't need instructions on how to do that. OP says **it works on some devices, but not on others"**

Answer (score 0):

The probably doesn't work on some devices because you are trying to pass too much data and you are overflowing the internal buffer that is used for IPC (interprocess communication). In general you shouldn't pass large arrays in an `Intent`. There are other ways of doing this:

- Share the data directly between multiple `Activities` by storing the data in a `public static` variable.
- Store the data in some persistent storage (file, SQLite database, `SharedPreferences`